# How to loop through all values in the array

Tags: php, javascript, loops

I am not very good with loops but I want to loop through every one of the session file values in the array. How is the foreach loop written in this situation and does it go in the php script or in the javascript code?

Below is the full php script where it uploads a file:

```
<?php

session_start();

$result = 0;
$errors = array ();
$dirImage = "ImageFiles/";


if (isset ( $_FILES ['fileImage'] ) && $_FILES ["fileImage"] ["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

    $fileName = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];

    $fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );


    $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
    $filePrifix = basename ( $fileName, "." . $fileExt );
    $i = 0;
    while ( file_exists ( $fileDst ) ) {
        $i ++;
        $fileDst = $dirImage . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filePrifix . "_" . $i . "." . $fileExt;

    }
    // Move the file

    if (count ( $errors ) == 0) {
        if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
            $result = 1;


        }
    }

}

$_SESSION ['fileImage'][] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];

?>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);</script>
```

Below is the javascript function which contains the json code:

```
function stopImageUpload(success){

      var imageNameArray = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;
      var result = '';



      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
            for (imagename in imageNameArray)
    {
         $('.listImage').append(imagename + '<br/>');

     }

      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }

      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','hidden');
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','hidden');

      $(".sbtnimage").removeAttr("disabled");
      $(".sbtnvideo").removeAttr("disabled");
      $(".sbtnaudio").removeAttr("disabled");


      return true;   
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand... what exactly is it that you want to loop through?

Comment: In my javascript code, it is suppose to output the name of uploaded files using the append method to append the $_SESSION variable in the 'imagename' variable.. But lets say I upload files 'dog.png', cat.png' and 'pig.png', it only appends the file name 'dog.png' for all the files on screen and not 'dog.png', cat.png' and 'pig.png'.

Comment: `$_SESSION ['fileImage']` will only contain one value.  Each time you run your upload code, you should add the value of `$_SESSION ['fileImage']` to another array and pass it to your JS function.

Comment: Can you show an example of this please as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION ['fileImage'][] = $_FILES ['fileImage']['name'];
```

Put that somewhere near the end of your PHP code.

```
var imageNameArray = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;
```

Change your Javascript `imagename` to that.

Then make a loop:

```
for (imagename in imageNameArray)
{
    if (success == 1)
    {
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
         $('.listImage').append(imagename + '<br/>');
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }
}
```

Comment: I have tested this but it appends '0' AND '1' for a file name after I uploaded a file, why is this happening?

Comment: I have update both php script and javascript function code above in the question